# Multiplication without multiplication for numbers in range 10-199, Vedic Maths

Tags: python-3.x, mathematics

```
print("This trick only works for range 10 to 199 included")

num1 = int(input("Enter 1st no.:"))
num2 = int(input("Enter 2nd no.:"))

max1 = max(num1, num2)
min1 = min(num1, num2 )


cond = (min1 > 9) and (max1 < 200)

def print2(res1, res2):
    res3 = num1+num2-100
    res4 = (num1-100) * (num2 -100)
    print(f""" 
Step 1 : 
{num1} is {num1-100} greater than 100
And
{num2} is {num2-100} greater than 100
Hence, 
The first 2 digits are 100+({num1-100})+({num2-100}) = {res3}
The last digits are {num1-100} * {num2 -100} = {res4}

Total {res1}{res2}
        """)
def print1(res1, res2):
    print(f""" 
Step 1 : 
{num1} is {num1-100} greater than 100
And
{num2} is {num2-100} greater than 100
Hence, 
The first 3 digits are 100+({num1-100})+({num2-100}) = {res1}
The last 2 digits are {num1-100} * {num2 -100} = {res2}
Total {res1}{res2}
        """)
        
def check_len(res1, res2):
    if len(str(res2)) < 2:
        res2 = str(0)+str(res2)
        print1(res1, res2)         
                 
    elif len(str(res2)) > 2:
         res1 = res1 + int(str(res2)[:-2])
         res2 = str(res2)[-2:]
         print2(res1, res2)     
         
     

def main(num1, num2):
    res1 = num1 + num2 - 100
    res2 = (num1-100)*(num2-100)


    if cond:
        
        if  num1 == num2 == 100:
             print(10000)         
                 
        elif  max1 < 100:
            if  len(str(res2)) == 2:
                res2 = str(res2)[-2:]
                print2(res1, res2)      
                
            else:    
                check_len(res1,res2) 
                   
        elif min1 > 100:                                                
             if  len(str(res2)) == 2: 
                print1(res1, res2) 
                
             else:
                 check_len(res1,res2)
                                      
        else :
            res1 = max1 - 100
            res2 = min1 - 100
            res3 = (min1 + res1) * 100
            res4 = res1*res2
            print(f""" 
Step 1 : {max(num1, num2)} - {100} = {res1}
Step 2 : ({num2} + {res1}) + 00 = {res3}
Step 3 : {res1} x {res2} = {res4}
Total 
{res3}+({res4}) = {res3+res4}
""")
                          
    else:
        print("This trick won't work", num1, num2)
        exit(0)
       
main(num1, num2)
```

Example 1: When the numbers are less than 100

```
This trick only works for range 10 to 199 included
Enter first number:56
Enter second number:67

Step 1 :
56 is -44 greater than 100
And
67 is -33 greater than 100
Hence,
The first 2 digits are 100+(-44)+(-33) = 23
The last digits are -44 * -33 = 1452

Total 3752


[Program finished]
```

Example 2: When greater than 100

```
This trick only works for range 10 to 199 included
Enter first number:110
Enter second number:120

Step 1 :
110 is 10 greater than 100
And
120 is 20 greater than 100
Hence,
The first 2 digits are 100+(10)+(20) = 130
The last digits are 10 * 20 = 200

Total 13200


[Program finished]
```

Example 3: One is smaller and one is greater than 100

```
This trick only works for range 10 to 199 included
Enter first number:126
Enter second number:98

Step 1 : 126 - 100 = 26
Step 2 : (98 + 26) + 00 = 12400
Step 3 : 26 x -2 = -52
Total
12400+(-52) = 12348


[Program finished]
```

We cannot change the output as kids might not understand technical jargon
Although, I admit its not that well formatted. I tried my best. The purpose is for kids to check stepwise where they are wrong.

Comment: I grew up in a generation where the essence was taught first. Any short-cuts were perhaps mentioned in passing and - if so - certainly afterwards. If the goal is to teach kids how to perform arithmetical computations quickly, just teach them how to install a calculator-app. I'm obviously biased, but if the goal is to teach kids arithmetic to get them started on the road of mathematics/logic in general, get the essence ingrained first, not the tricks.

Comment: in a competitive exam, you have to know trick, bcos  calc not allowed. it's better if we teach them from start, rather than learning at later age

Comment: if num1 in cond and  num2  in cond: - is this working?

Comment: refactored the code but forgot to do other necessary changes... sorry, correction done

Comment: @Subham: I question the validity of evaluating the question (solely) in the context of competitive exams, but even there "calcs" are allowed (you're allowed to calculate anything using the machinery of your brain). I can't imagine a (serious) competitive exam where employing a trick that work on a 200/∞ ᵗʰ of all integers and (moreover) is computationally just as efficient as the real deal has merit.

Comment: [https://afeias.com/faq/can-candidates-use-calculators-upsc-civil-services-exam/] Please read the first statement. Anyways its student who wanted me to make a project using python. I was able to help them with as much python I knew. There are many such tricks on YouTube. By statistics, this particular trick gives extra 15sec per calculation.

Comment: @Subham If I follow the afeias-link of your previous comment it says "Uh-Oh! It looks like you are lost!" so I can't read the first statement (unless that was it). If they removed the page out of ethical reasons (because "teaching tricks over techniques" is bad, or "speed is more important than understanding" is wrong), I'm ok with that. Just to make sure: don't assume my opinion is personally addressed to you. It's not. Like you, I would have enjoyed coding something students requested.

Comment: Google search if calc is allowed for IAS exams India. It will say Not for UPSC Civil Services Preliminary Exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
print("This trick only works for range 10 to 199 included")

num1 = int(input("Enter 1st no.:"))
num2 = int(input("Enter 2nd no.:"))

max1 = max(num1, num2)
min1 = min(num1, num2 )


COND = (min1 > 9) and (max1 < 200)

def print2(res1, res2):
    res3 = num1+num2-100
    res4 = (num1-100) * (num2 -100)
    print(f""" 
Step 1 : 
{num1} is {num1-100} greater than 100
And
{num2} is {num2-100} greater than 100
Hence, 
The first 2 digits are 100+({num1-100})+({num2-100}) = {res3}
The last digits are {num1-100} * {num2 -100} = {res4}

Total {res1}{res2}
        """)
def print1(res1, res2):
    print(f""" 
Step 1 : 
{num1} is {num1-100} greater than 100
And
{num2} is {num2-100} greater than 100
Hence, 
The first 3 digits are 100+({num1-100})+({num2-100}) = {res1}
The last 2 digits are {num1-100} * {num2 -100} = {res2}
Total {res1}{res2}
        """)
        
def check_len(res1, res2):
    if len(str(res2)) < 2:
        res2 = str(0)+str(res2)
        print1(res1, res2)         
                 
    elif len(str(res2)) > 2:
         res1 = res1 + int(str(res2)[:-2])
         res2 = str(res2)[-2:]
         print2(res1, res2)     
         
     

def main(num1, num2):
    res1 = num1 + num2 - 100
    res2 = (num1-100)*(num2-100)

    if not COND:
        print("This trick won't work", num1, num2)
        return 
        
    if  num1 == 100 and num2 == 100:
             print(10000)
             return      
                 
    if  max1 < 100:
        if  len(str(res2)) == 2:
            res2 = str(res2)[-2:]
            print2(res1, res2)
            return   
        check_len(res1,res2) 
        return       
            
    if min1 > 100:                                                
         if  len(str(res2)) == 2: 
            print1(res1, res2) 
            return    
         check_len(res1,res2)
         return
      
    res1 = max1 - 100
    res2 = min1 - 100
    res3 = (min1 + res1) * 100
    res4 = res1 * res2
    print(f""" 
Step 1 : {max(num1, num2)} - {100} = {res1}
Step 2 : ({num2} + {res1}) + 00 = {res3}
Step 3 : {res1} x {res2} = {res4}
Total 
{res3}+({res4}) = {res3+res4}
""")
                          
       
main(num1, num2)

```
````